# what is the mysql-database for?

Tags: mysql

When I install mysql, there is a mysql-database with tables like user, tables_priv, columsn_priv etc. What is this for? - I have on the otherhand a database called information_schema - there are the schema-information-tables. Now, I am asking me, what is the mysql-database good for?

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Come on folks... OP could admittedly have bothered to read the docs a bit before asking, but it's not a question that warrants 3 down-votes.

Comment: @all - I have read the doc's. I think, I have not clear asked. I understand, what is the database information_schema for. But I haven't understand for what is the database mysql (I mean the database - NOT mysql as dbs) good. Now, with the anser I have marked as answer and the data which is in the tables of the database, it is clear. - I think, this question does not earn the down-votes :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` database primarily contains permissions information. The tables in it define what MySQL userscan log in, using which passwords, from where, and what level of access they have to various databases, tables, columns, stored procedures, and other objects. It can be written to directly, and is also modified automatically by `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements.

The `information_schema` database, is primarily concerned with describing what exists. It contains a set of tables which represent views on structural things that exist in your MySQL installation, including databases, tables, columns, and various system information and statistics. It is read-only, as much of the information it displays doesn't even make sense to try to modify.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL database is the catalog. (The Postgres equivalent would be `pg_catalog`.) It contains things such as defined databases, users, tables, triggers, constraints, permissions, etc.

The information schema is a set of (standardized) views to access this catalog. So, basically the same, except that these views are not supposed to differ from a database flavor to the next.